# How to upload an excel file to azure blob in a readable format?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am uploading an excel file to azure storage container. When the file gets uploaded, and I try to download it back from the portal and open it, the open fails because the format of the file and extension do not match. Also, there is no size in the size column corresponding to the file. I cannot spot the error. The code is in asp.net core 3.1 with c#.
Here is my code

```
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString); // to the azure account
CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName); // container in which the file will be uploaded
blob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(f); // f is file name
await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(s); // this is a memory stream
blob.Properties.ContentType = fileType;
```

Comment: _"Also, there is no size in the size column corresponding to the file."_ - > did you seek back to the beginning of the `MemoryStream` before trying to upload it? If not you're uploading from the end of the `MemoryStream` (i.e. after any content you write to it). Please can you edit your question to include the generation of `s`.

Comment: Also please avoid adding unnecessary tags. This situation isn't unique to ASP.NET Core, and especially not ASP.NET Core 3.1 or ASP.NET Core MVC.

Comment: Either you are not uploading in binary format or you are loosing bytes at the end of the file.  Use a tool like Beyond Compare to compare original file to final file.  See if there are errors in the middle or just at the end of the file.

Comment: Could you please provide all you code used to upload file?

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? It may help more people.

Answer (score 1):

According to my test, we can use the following code to upload excel file to Azure blob storage

1. Install SDK

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob -Version 11.1.1
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles -Version 2.2.0
```

2. My excel file(.xlsx)
   [image]
3. Code

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var filepath = @"D:\test.xlsx";
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("<connection string>");
            var cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("test1");
            var blob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(Path.GetFileName(filepath));

            blob.Properties.ContentType = Get(Path.GetFileName(filepath));

            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filepath))
            {

                   await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);


            }
            //download file
            filepath = @"D:\test\" + blob.Name;
            using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(filepath))
            {

                await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
            }


        }

        // get the file content type
        static string Get(string fileName)
        {
            var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            string contentType;
            if (!provider.TryGetContentType(fileName, out contentType))
            {
                contentType = "application/octet-stream";
            }
            return contentType;
        }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you assigning the content type as octet stream if it fails? Can I upload a Excel file with Octet sream content type?